# Embed Flow in Lightning App builder Page

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

Just wanted to know if anyone is aware how to pass other value instead of RecordId to a flow from Lightning Page.

[image]

Like from my opportunity detail page, I want to pass the seller Id to a flow. Is there is any way to send the value?
I do tried wid {!record.seller__c} or {!Opportunity.Seller__c} but it didn work.

I read the notes here but didn't find any about the syntax:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_internal_lab.htm

Comment: Once you have the opportunity id you can run a lookup in the flow to get any other information you need.

Comment: @gorav: Yes I knw that option,  but i was looking if I can pass the associated record details apart form Id.

Comment: Curious as to the advantage of doing that, since it's so easy to get the rest of the info from the id.

Comment: @gorav: wanted to avoid the fast look up and thought if the object values can be passed along with record id